# Not able to call Rest API from node-salesforce library

Tags: rest-api, jsforce, node-salesforce

I am trying to hit salesforce restAPI using node-salesforce(primarily - jsforce)
and here is the code

```
var jsforce = require('node-salesforce');

restService.post("/searchAppointment", function (req, mainres) {

    try {
        var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
            loginUrl: config.salesforceLoginURL
        });
        var _body = { "territoryIds": ["0Hh5e0000001CNxCAM"], "workTypeGroupId": "0VS5e0000000vguGAA", "startTime": "2022-07-18T00:00:00.000Z", "endTime": "2022-07-30T00:00:00.000Z", "filterByResources": ["0Hn3K0000004S1vSAE"] };
        var _request = {
            url: '/services/data/v55.0/scheduling/getAppointmentCandidates',
            post: 'post',
            body: _body,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        };
        conn.login(config.salesforceUserName, config.salesforcePassword + config.salesforceSecurityToken, function (err, userInfo) {
            conn.request(_request, function (err, resp) {
                return mainres.json({
                    userInfo
                });

            });

        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

But I am always getting Request time out error.

Tried by changing the URL to relative URL also but still the same issue

Comment: Have you tried by passing consumer key/secret in below block

`var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
            loginUrl: config.salesforceLoginURL
        });`

Comment: You're looking at a deprecated version of the library. Try https://jsforce.github.io/